# Why doesn't this swift function work?

Tags: string, function, swift

This function takes two string arguments. It is supposed to return the first one as dashes except where the character is somewhere inside of the second argument. Example:

```
dashes_except("hello", except: "lo") -> --llo
```

The function works fine when the except argument is only one letter but fails when it is longer than one. It just returns dashes. I'm pretty new to Swift so some help would be super appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
func dashes_except(word: String,except: String) -> String { 

    var loc = [String]()
    for (index, character) in enumerate(word) {
        loc.append(String(character))
    }
    var loc_except = [String]()
    for (index, character) in enumerate(except) {     
        loc_except.append(String(character))
    }
    for x in 0..<loc.count {
        for y in 0..<loc_except.count {
            if loc[x] != loc_except[y] {
                loc[x] = "-"
            }  
        }   
    }
    return "".join(loc)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the inner loop

```
    for y in 0..<loc_except.count {
        if loc[x] != loc_except[y] {
            loc[x] = "-"
        }
    }
```

`loc[x]` is replaced by the dash "-" if it is different from *any*
characters in `loc_except`. This will always be the case if the
exception string has at least two different characters.

You can solve this using `contains()`:

```
for x in 0..<loc.count {
    if !contains(loc_except, loc[x]) {
        loc[x] = "-"
    }
}
```

That being said, your function can be concisely written as

```
func dashes_except(word: String,except: String) -> String {

    return String(Array(word).map( { contains(except, $0) ? $0 : "-" } ))
}
```

Here,

- `Array(word)` creates an array with all the characters in 
  the string (what you did with the `enumerate()` loop),
- `map { }` replaces all characters which are not contained in
  the exception string by a dash, and
- `String( ... )` converts the character array to a string again
  (what you did with `"".join()`).

Comment: Alright so I understand why it is not working, but I can't find a solution. I tried using a break but I can't figure it out. Could you tell me how to maybe better find if some list value is inside of another? In python I would just use the 'in' keyword for things like this, does Swift have something similar?

Comment: In those cases I usually recommend to use regex.

Comment: @jonathanlv7: Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you! I got this problem solved but I do have another question. I'm trying to use Array(string) and it keeps telling me that I need to use Array(arrayLiteral:String) but that doesn't work. Why isn't it just letting me use Array(string)?

Comment: @jonathanlv7: which Xcode version are you using? The above code has been tested with Xcode 6.3.2.

Comment: Okay well the code I'm having a hard time with isn't related to the function above. It's in the same project, but its for a different function. I defined a variable called secret_word in the first line inside of the ViewController class. Then we I try and reference it in another method using Array(secret_word) it tells me to label the argument with arrayLiteral. I went on a website called swift online to test the code and tried using Array(string) - which worked - and what it wants me to do which is Array(arrayLiteral:string) - which did not work. I think I'll post a new question

Comment: I posted a new question. Please take a look if you get a chance. Thank you !